# Rename matrix columns using colnames

Tags: r, matrix, rename

In R, I want the columns of a matrix to be named "NewName1" and "NewName2" rather than "X1" and "X2".

```
# Example matrix to change column names for
xxx <- matrix(c(3, 2, 5, 6, 54, 8, NA, 8, 13, 4, 2, 1, NA, NA), 7, 2,
       dimnames=list(as.character(1:7), c("X1", "X2")))
```

How can I change the column names without listing all of the new column names out? I have a matrix with 80 columns, so I don't want to name each new column individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily using `paste`.

```
# Example matrix
m <- matrix(0, 10, 10)

# Rename columns: NewName1, NewName2,..., NewName10
colnames(m) <- paste("NewName", 1:10, sep="")
```